# Tomcat with BIRT view autodeploy: JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD

Tags: maven, tomcat, birt

I have a Birt View report that I've integrated on a .jsp page. It's running on a Tomcat server. When I manually place the .war from the webapp package build into the Tomcat Server it works and the page loads with no error.

Now I want to autodeploy it from my project (IDE is Intellij with Maven), but I get:

"JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD. The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource."

I've added the plugin for Tomcat7 in my pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/WebApp</path>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

and added the server in .m2/settings.xml/

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>tomcat</username>
        <password>tomcat</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The correct user in tomcat-users is added.

I tried to add some settings like:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

And (in web.xml from tomcat)

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <http-methode>POST</http-methode>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But I still get that error. Some who could help me? I'm trying to get this working for a full day now.

Comment: curious, should the web.xml node have an `http-methode` element? is that spelled incorrectly in the working project?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it sorted.

We forgot to add our poi into the other xml too.